# Query that gets only the records needed to the page using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, iqueryable

I want to use LINQ's `IQueryable` that gives me the query that gets only the records needed to the page based on the page size I have given.

I have used this:

```
System.Linq.IQueryable<DataTable> ds = 
    (from m in dttableDetails.TableName select m).Take(page_size).Skip(offset);
```

but it is showing me an error. I need the returned type as `Datatable/Dataset`. How to do this? Please help. The error is:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Data.DataTable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Comment: Who is the consumer of 'ds' or who do you use 'ds'?

Comment: And the error you got was...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dttableDetails.TableName` returns the name of the table, so `from m in dttableDetails.TableName select m` returns an enumerable which iterates over the characters in the string, hence you get an `IEnumerable<char>`

Try

```
var results = (from m in dttableDetails select m).Take(page_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help [c-sharp corner](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/VIMAL.LAKHERA/LINQResultsetToDatatable06242008042629AM/LINQResultsetToDatatable.aspx)